# Not saving data by Hive

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I want to save the value of a text field using **Hive** so that the value is not lost when the application is opened and closed.
But this is not done correctly.

Code:

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        box.put(1, userNameController.text);
        var name = box.get(1);
        task?.userName = userNameController.text;
        print(name);
        print(task?.userName);
      },
      child: Text('Save'),
    ),
```

Here I have **put** the input value with key 1 and then **get** it.
In my **model class**, I have a **userName** whose input value of that **textfield** is supposed to be equal to that class model, and finally by calling that model and class, I will display the input value as text.
But the input value of the textfield is not equal to the user class! And when printing in the console, I also encounter **null**.

[image: Model]

Comment: How is that `task` related to Hive?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan - It is not relevant at the moment. I have made the box hive normally and did not connect it to my data model.

Comment: Can you clarify the output to each print statement?

Comment: @DhafinRayhan - In the first print command, the same input that is entered in the text field is shown. But in the second print command, the return value is null. In fact, in the second printout, nothing is displayed in the data model. That's the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing the `task` object is null when you call it, so the assignment does nothing. Have you check it? Or if not maybe you can show how the model class is defined

Comment: @DhafinRayhan - Yes that's right.
In the models class, the userName value is normally empty, and the userName is supposed to take its value from the textfield, and then when the value of the textfield is poured into the userName, it can be displayed.

Comment: No, I mean not the `userName`, but the `task` object might be null. Check with if (task == null) print('something');

Comment: @DhafinRayhan - Your guess was right. The return value was null. I uploaded a photo of the model class.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is, you have to instantiate the object first before assigning its properties to some values. In this example code:

```dart
taskModel? task;
task?.userName = 'something';
```

The second line does nothing. You have to use a constructor first:

```dart
taskModel? task; // It's ok to define first, and instantiate later

// Somewhere
task = taskModel(
  // put the required parameters
  // ...
);
task?.userName = "something";
```

Now that last line will actually assign the value "something" to the `userName` property of `task`.